# Why it is not possible to use setOnClickListener directly for compound view?

Tags: android, onclick, android-compound-view

I have simple compound view with `ConstraintLayout` as a root. Attributes like `clickable`, `focusable` are enabled. It is perfectly shown on my layout. I want to handle when it gets clicked. Approach is simple, but it does not work:

```
myCompoundView.setOnClickListener {
     /// Handle click here 
}
```

But that callback is not called at all. I really don't understand why it refuses to be called. Another approach would be following:

1. Implement OnClickListener for your compound view
2. Call `setOnClickListener` on `init` of your compound view
3. Create your own callback and use it when `onClick` gets called

But this approach requires more code and it just implements what already made. Possibly, callback can become null at some point. So, my question is why simple `setOnClickListener` does not work? If it does not work, how to be notified when my compound view gets clicked?

There is a code if you need:

/// my compound view below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout  xmlns:android="http://sch`enter code here`emas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    >

     /// some views here 
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is how I use it:

```
<sample.sample.com.ChooserView
    android:id="@+id/familyStateChooserView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:chooseLabel="@string/family_kind"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    />
```

Here is its class:

```
class ChooserView(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs) {

    init {

        LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.chooser_view, this, true)

        val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ChooserView, 0, 0)

        label.text = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.ChooserView_chooseLabel)

        typedArray.recycle()

    }


    }
```

Comment: disable `clickable` and `focusable` for child view ,may it works

Comment: please show your code.

Comment: check listner is setting or not..might be you are setting listner in the block that is not getting called

Answer (score 0):

I found some solution. Let the `id` of my compound view's root layout be called as `root`. If we set `setOnClickListener` as following:

```
myCompoundView.root.setOnClickListener {
     /// Handle here 
}
```

It magically works somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your are clicking on parent view.

it may not work if child view `clickable` and `focusable` are `true`

so try setting `false` for `clickable` and `focusable` on child view and then try

hope it helps..

Comment: Look, it have compound view that has ConstraintsLayout as a root (parent) layout, which has focusable, clickable enabled. Its child views do not have such a attributes. I don't know how to try your suggestion. Disabling clickable, focusable for parent view?

Comment: may be it is by default considered as `true` , if it is not work please show your code

Comment: Didn't try your approach, but showed code in the question

Comment: I answered my own question below, why it works? Can you explain?